# Find all empty fields in admin

Tags: field, admin, channels

I'm working with a fairly large data set in one of my channels and I was hoping there was a way maybe in admin to show me all the live entries where certain fields are empty. I want to be able to easier find where I'm missing data. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a super-easy way to figure this out off of the top of my head.

There are a couple of not-so-easy ways to figure it out, though.

1) Find the column in the `craft_content` (or the equivalent Matrix content table) and find all the rows with empty values.

2) From either a plugin (PHP) or a template (Twig), write some code that grabs all of the entries you are interested in and loops through them checking if the particular field has a value or not.